# File Explorer using Dojo Tree from an Array

Tags: json, dojo, dijit.tree

I have an array of file names/paths. Lets say it contains:

- File1.txt
- Folder1/File2.txt
- Folder1/File3.txt
- Folder2/File4.txt
- Folder3/Folder4/File5.txt
- Folder3/File6.txt
- NewFile.txt

Now I want to create a Dojo Tree which basically displays this information in a tree structure with root as "Files" and below it appears a tree like this

- Files (ROOT)

  - File1.txt
  - Folder1

    - File2.txt
    - File3.txt
  - Folder2

    - File4.txt
  - Folder3

    - Folder4

      - File5.txt
    - File6.txt
  - NewFile.txt

I was able to create a JSON form single level tree structure. As I am hard pressed for time I need a algorithm/code snippet which can create my desired JSON file. Any ideas!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at giveSortedArray() function (yeah I suck at function naming):

http://jsfiddle.net/QDAjz/

I used dojo.store.Memory for easier fetching of existing folders but I'm sure there are some other (possible better) solutions.